# I don't like [free-software]. I like the definition though :)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We've got [free-software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-software).

> Use this tag for free software, defined as computer software that gives users the freedom to run the software for any purpose as well as to study, modify, and distribute the original software and the adapted versions. (consider free as in freedom ; don't confuse with freeware)

Ummmm... Isn't this the entire site?

While I like [free-software](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-software), most of these questions are really about the [free-software-definition](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-software-definition).

Comment: I see no use cases against this, but I'd love to hear from anyone who does. I hope I'm not overlooking anything. Is there any question that should be tagged free-software but not free-software-definition?

Comment: @curiousdannii Not necessarily. The core of those questions are attempting to suggest two different things. Same tags, but different proposals.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Well they're essentially the same, and if you want to propose something else then you could comment on that post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a very populated tag (4 questions) and they all could be changed to -definition IMO. I currently see no reason not to merge.

Comment: I second the motion

Comment: Better to make the definition tag a duplicate of the other - all FSD questions are about free software, but not the other way round.

Comment: @curiousdannii how does that make any sense? This entire site is about free-software! What on earth is the point of such a tag?

Comment: @curiousdannii this is true. Looking at the current body of questions however, all current FS tagged questions are eligible to be tagged FSD, And I can't come up with use-cases for the FS tag that are not better tagged differently. In all cases FS wouldn't overlap with FSD, I think the FS tag is too broad.